# how to use generics to merge two function in one in golang

Tags: go

i have this two functions and i want to implement generics on it. just to know i tried `interface{}` and `[t any]` and `(t any)` and all field. and this is the code. if  you know how to use generics to make this two functions in one function. just write the code

```
func concat(args ...[]directory_account_price_discount_tax) []directory_account_price_discount_tax {
    concated := []directory_account_price_discount_tax{}
    for _, i := range args {
        concated = append(concated, i...)
    }
    return concated
}

func concat_strings_slice(args ...[]string) []string {
    concated := []string{}
    for _, i := range args {
        concated = append(concated, i...)
    }
    return concated
}
```

and the struct of `directory_account_price_discount_tax` is

```
type directory_account_price_discount_tax struct {
    directory_no         []int
    Account              string
    Price, Discount, Tax float64
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have code you tried that generated an error, but you didn't show it.  The non-generics version is good to include.  Please also include the generics version that didn't work for you, and the error you got

Comment: @Daniel Farrell the error is when i make all `directory_account_price_discount_tax` is `interface{}` and have no error inside the function . it return error `cannot use concat(s.Fifo, s.Lifo, s.Wma, s.Service) (type []interface {}) as type []directory_account_price_discount_tax in assignment` and `cannot use s.Fifo (type []directory_account_price_discount_tax) as type []interface {} in argument to concat` and what i want to do. is to make my function like the `append` function. i mean i want to accept all data type

Comment: Now that generics are here, you can do https://go.dev/play/p/WhRvB3fr5wK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to write a function that concatenates slices of an arbitrary type.

```
func concat(args ...interface{}) interface{} {
    n := 0
    for _, arg := range args {
        n += reflect.ValueOf(arg).Len()
    }
    v := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf(args[0]), 0, n)
    for _, arg := range args {
        v = reflect.AppendSlice(v, reflect.ValueOf(arg))
    }
    return v.Interface()
}
```

The function panics when there are no arguments or the arguments are not the same type.

Use the `concat` function like this:

```
s := concat([]string{"a", "b"}, []string{"c", "d"}).([]string)
```

Note the use of the [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to get result as the desired type.

There is a better solution using Go's [type parameters](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md) feature, but that feature is not released as of  the time I am writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can accept any kind of value and append them to an array.

```golang
func concat(args ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    concated := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for _, i := range args {
        concated = append(concated, i)
    }
    return concated
}
```

But when you need to access the fields of `directory_account_price_discount_tax` you need type assertion like this

```golang
arr := concat(/* some directory_account_price_discount_tax type values */)
v := arr[0].(directory_account_price_discount_tax)
```

Comment: when i enter `[]string` in the `args` like this by using your code `concat(liabilities_normal, equity_normal)` it return `cannot use liabilities_normal (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to concat` that mean it just accept `[]interface{}` like this `concat([]interface{}{"k", "i"}, []interface{}{"e", "y"})` and that don't help me

Comment: try the updated answer.